# If at larger distances you are measuring the potential difference (voltage) of a material, does it make the value of the current decrease?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

How would one create a graph to find the resistance of the material using the the voltage and current at different lenghts?

Answer (score 1):

> If at larger distances you are measuring the potential difference (voltage) of a material, does it make the value of the current decrease?

**No**, measuring over different points across a component does **not** change the measured current. The current is the same throughout at every point (just as much charge must pass every point per second - otherwise some would be accumulated somewhere.)

> How would one create a graph to find the resistance of the material using the the voltage and current at different lenghts?

Use Ohm's law:
$$V=RI$$

The current $I$ will be constant as just stated. So measure the voltage $V$ across two points and you can use the measured $V$ and $I$ to find an $R$. Then do the same across other points and you'll have more values of $R$ to plot.

**A sidenote:**

Saying "*resistance of the material*" sounds slightly off:

- A **component** has a **resistance** $R$ while a **material** has a **resistivity** $\rho$.

$R$ depends on geometry and $\rho$ does not. Different pieces of the same material can have different $R$ but they all have the same $\rho$.

$\rho$ is what you can look up in materials data tables. From this *and* the geometry of whatever component you are building you can calculate an $R$ - for typical column-shaped components this formula with cross-section area $A$ and length $L$ can be used:

$$R=\rho\frac LA$$

Comment: Thanks, but voltage across different points do change? So at larger distances voltage increases right?

Comment: @SirSmiles, are you talking about something with constant current flowing through it?  If so, see the equation above and how $R$ is related to a changing $L$.  You already know $V=IR$ and $I$ is constant.

Comment: Like if a current is going through a metal rod, and you measure the potential difference across different lengths on the rod. So ideally if there is a larger distance there is more potential difference (voltage) ?

Comment: @Sir Smiles Yes. Combine the two equations in the answer to get $V = /frac{I\rho}{A}\, L$ where $L$ is (more or less, at least) the length of the part of the rod between the points you are measuring. Since $I$, $\rho$ and $A$ are constant, $V$ is directly proportional to the distance $L$ between the points; e.g. doubling the distance doubles the potential difference.